# Activate the button in a form when old values are not equals that new values in ANGULARJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I am trying to do an edit form in angular. When I am editing the fields in my form they show the old values (typical edit form). The problem is when I try to make disable or enable the submit button form when the new values are totally different from the old values in all fields. The original idea is save changes and do calls to my server if the news values are not equals.

How could I do this in angularJs?

This is my angular controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    app.controller('ProjectController', ProjectController);
    ProjectController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$q', 'ProjectService', 'currentUser', '$location'];

    function ProjectController($scope, $http, $q, ProjectService, currentUser, $location) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.init = init;
        vm.getProjects = getProjects;
        vm.createProject = createProject;
        vm.projectToEdit =  {
            name: '',
            version: '',
            suffix: '',
            description: ''
        };
        vm.editProject = editProject;
        vm.projectToCreate= {
            name: '',
            version: '',
            suffix: '',
            description: ''
        }
        vm.projectFilter = {
            name: '',
            version: '',
            page: 1,
            projectId: ''
        };
        vm.listProject = [];

        function init()
        {
            getProjects();
        }

        function getProjects()
        {
            ProjectService.getProjects().then(responseGet);
            function responseGet(response)
            {
                vm.listProject = response.data;
            }
        }

        function editProject(position)
        {
            vm.projectToEdit = vm.listProject[position];
        }

        function createProject()
        {
            ProjectService.createProject(vm.projectToCreate).then(respongeCreateProject);

            function responseCreateProject(response)
            {

            }
        }

    }

})();
```

this is my form:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit project</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="ProjectName">Project name</label>
                            <input class="form-control" ng-model="projCtr.projectToEdit.Name" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Suffix">Suffix</label>
                            <input class="form-control" ng-model="projCtr.projectToEdit.Suffix" />
                            </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Version">Version</label>
                            <input class="form-control" ng-model="projCtr.projectToEdit.Version" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Description">Description</label>
                                <input class="form-control" ng-model="projCtr.projectToEdit.Description" />
                            </div>
                        </div>                    
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Right now my flow assigns in a new value the fields to edit, called vm.projectToEdit. In the function editProject(position) I get the array position where is my object to edit.
Kind regards

Comment: please provide code or fiddle

Comment: ok, gimme few minutes